# how to add multiple tinyMce with dom javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce, rte

Please help me, how to add multiple textarea wit tinymce ..!
I wanted to like this result:

examples of my scripts is here:
http://tuto-rial.com/index2.txt

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will need to use two separate tinymce init functions.
I guess you have two textareas at your page at the beginning.
The first one gets activated on page load using an init like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode:      "exact",
        elements : "id_of_first_textarea",
        ...
    });
});
```

On "Add new"-buttonclick you do the following:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode:      "exact",
    elements : "id_of_second_textarea",
    // deactivates the editor body
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
            // you may also add a click handler here to disable the focus of the editor body
            $(ed.getBody()).attr('contenteditable', false);
        }); 
    },
    ...
});
```

The "Get Content" buttonaction does the following:

```
var content = tinymce.get('textarea_id_of_the_desired_editor').getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the example on their site: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/multiple_configs.php

- or -

You could always put the second one in an iframe and on your form submit communicate with the iframe to get the content, but it is a less elegant solution

Comment: I want to add TinyMCE to click, the image I was wrong in his earlier croping.

Comment: you can see an example like this picture ..
http://tuto-rial.com/add_multiple_tinyMCE.png

Comment: i think this is what you want then: http://blog.dileno.com/archive/201102/adding-tinymce-editor-dynamically-and-get-its-value/

Comment: the example referenced in @JefferyAWooden's original comment has moved: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/multiple_configs.php